# Product Listing page

Tags: magento-1.9

I am new to magento.I am using version 1.9. I want to display filter and category section above listed product of the category in small resolution.

But in my case its occurring vice versa.I am unable to find file from which it has been called.

These are line of code that is appearing in inspect element.
I want to exchange the div's position i-e- first i want to have this "col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-18 em-col-left em-sidebar" and then the other one.
I'm doing a maintenance task so i dont know from which file the main div's are coming.

Can someone tell me how to do it?

Comment: can you tell me which div you want to change?

Comment: you can also on template path hint in magento http://help.sweettoothrewards.com/article/434-how-do-i-turn-on-template-path-hints

Comment: <div class="col-sm-18 col-sm-push-6 em-col-main">

Comment: <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-18 em-col-left em-sidebar">

Comment: i want to exchange these two div's position

Comment: yes i have turned the hints on but it's not showing me from which file these divs are coming.The hints that are shown are the files of inner div's but i want to exchange position of  main div's

Comment: for category page you can check `app/design/frontend/YourPackage/YourTheme/template/catalog/product/list.phtml ` and also   `app/design/frontend/YourPackage/YourTheme/template/catalog/category/view.phtml ` these two files mainly responsible for that page please check in those files

Comment: it shows the files of inner divs' ...what i want to do is display navigation filter on top of product listing in small resolution as it appears below of product listing now. but i can't find the file from from which i can exchange position of outer div's

Answer (score 2):

```
//if you want to change order of div use this in media query

 <div class="maindiv">
    <div class="div1">
        <span>some text 1</span>
    </div>
    <div class="div2">
        <span>some text 2</span>
    </div>
    <div class="div3">
        <span>some text 3</span>
    </div>
 </div>


 .maindiv{display: flex;flex-flow:column;}
 .div3{order:1;}
 .div1{order:2;}
 .div2{order:3;}


Result:

some text 3
some text 1
some text 2
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.i have tried it,it does changes the order but responsiveness of page gets disturbed.Its magento default behavior that it first displays products and then the filters.What i want to do is first display the filters then the products.